# Non member function needs to print out an array via pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need to write a Matrix class which has a pointer to an array of doubles. I need to print these doubles out on a 'matrix-way'. I made a private 'double *m' which references to an array (see constructor). Now, the operator<< is a non member function and I don't know how to print out the array where the pointer points to..

```
 class Matrix {
 private:
     double * m;
     int size;
 public:
     Matrix(const int rows = 2, const int columns = 2);
     Matrix(const Matrix& matrix);
     Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& matrix);
     double * getM() const {return m;}
     friend const Matrix& operator *(int x, const Matrix& m);
     friend const Matrix& operator *(const Matrix& matrix,int x);
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Matrix& matrix);

     int getSize() const {return size;}
     void setSize(const int s){size = s;}
     virtual ~Matrix();
     };

    Matrix::Matrix(const int rows, const int columns) {
           size = rows * columns;
           m = new double[size];
           for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            *(m+(i+1)) = i+1;
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already declared your `operator <<` a `friend` of your `Matrix` class, the operator has access to all of the `matrix`'s private members, including the pointer member `m` and the `int` member `size`. You can make full use of them in the implementation of your operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Matrix& matrix) {
    double *a = matrix.m;
    int s = matrix.size;
    ...
    // Do printing here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why my destructor doesn't work, i always get the error he is feeding unallocated data.

    Matrix::~Matrix() {
     if(m){
      delete m;
     }
    }

Comment: @GNIUS Most likely it's because your copy constructor or assignment operator did something wrong (or forgot to do something). You may want to post a separate question with the code of your constructors, and a test that produces the error.